# Average number of actions per day of the week using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have a count of the number of event per hour as follows:

```
np.random.seed(42)
idx = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-01-14', freq='1H')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6], size=idx.shape[0]), index=idx, columns=['count'])
df.head()

Out[3]:
                     count
2017-01-01 00:00:00      4
2017-01-01 01:00:00      5
2017-01-01 02:00:00      3
2017-01-01 03:00:00      5
2017-01-01 04:00:00      5
```

If I want to know the **total** number of events per day of the week, I can do either:

```
df.pivot_table(values='count', index=df.index.dayofweek, aggfunc='sum')
```

or

```
df.groupby(df.index.dayofweek).sum()
```

Both yields:

```
Out[4]:
   count
0    161
1    170
2    164
3    133
4    169
5     98
6    172
```

However, if I want to compute the **average number of events per weekday**, the following

```
df.pivot_table(values='count', index=df.index.dayofweek, aggfunc='mean') # [#1]
```

is ***wrong*!!** This approach uses the sum (as computed above), and divides it by the number of hours that appeared in each day of the week.

The workaround I found is:

```
df_by_day = df.resample('1d').sum()
df_by_day.pivot_table(values='count', index=df_by_day.index.dayofweek, aggfunc='mean')
```

That is, first resample to days, and then pivot it. Somehow the approach in `[#1]` feel natural to me. Is there a more pythonic way to achieve what I want? Why does without resampling the mean is wrongly computed?

Comment: You still need `resample` `df_by_day.groupby(df_by_day.index.dayofweek)['count'].mean()`

Comment: @Wen Added your answer as a community wiki (meaning I don't get any rep from it). If you decide to post an answer, I'll delete it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ dude, it is ok ~ I am here helping and getting helped , not for the point ~ :-)

Comment: @Wen so the workaround I mentioned in the OP is indeed the way out, right? I still find the behavior of the `pivot_table` as in `[#1]` (or in `groupby`) little counter intuitive. Is it just me?

Comment: @Dror as far as I know , `resample` is indeed

Comment: @Wen Now I also understand this, but this is after investigating this matter for couple of hours. Did you understand this from the documentation? For me, the documentation suggested that it's enough to do `[#1]` (similarly to the correct behavior when using `sum`).

Comment: @Dror you can think , they are doing `mean()=sum()/count()`
and in your case , without `resample`  result from `sum` should be the same but the `count` is different, that is why mean give back different result

Comment: @Dror if the answer addresses your question, remember you can accept it (It's a community wiki so I don't get any rep from it).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Note that this very solution appears in the OP :) I guess the answer here would be to explain that by using the hourly sampled data, the count for each day of the week is wrong (counts the hours that occur at each weekday) and in turn the mean is wrong.

Comment: It's a community wiki! Feel free to edit ;)

Answer (score 5):

[Resample first using `df.resample` and then `df.groupby`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45922291/average-number-of-action-per-day-of-the-week-using-pandas#comment78803670_45922291):

```
df = df.resample('1d').sum()
print(df)

            count
2017-01-01     92
2017-01-02     86
2017-01-03     86
2017-01-04     90
2017-01-05     64
2017-01-06     82
2017-01-07     97
2017-01-08     80
2017-01-09     75
2017-01-10     84
2017-01-11     74
2017-01-12     69
2017-01-13     87
2017-01-14      1

out = df.groupby(df.index.dayofweek)['count'].mean()
print(out)

1    85.0
2    82.0
3    66.5
4    84.5
5    49.0
6    86.0
Name: count, dtype: float64
```